# XML Find and replace Based on property

Tags: xml

I need help with this little project, i have two files, one in Vietnam/Chinese and other in English, and i want to find the elements identical in both of them (5k+) and replace,

Example:

```
VIET: <Property name="GM_SUSSECC" content="đem ngươi {@}{@}" type="2"/>
ENG:  <Property name="GM_SUSSECC" content="{@}{@} Logged In" type="2"/>
```

So, I want to find the same name in english and replace with its content.Its like translating.

I tried using excel, but it seems it loose format and break my xml, 
So does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: what language or toolkit would work for you?

Comment: any tool would be useful, i tried some paid XML editors, but they failed to do what i need

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh). Create a hash table of the English contents keyed by the name, then replace it in the Vietnamese file:

```
open eng.xml ;
$eng := hash ../@name //Property/@content ;
open viet.xml ;
for //Property {
    my $viet = xsh:lookup('eng', @name) ;
    if $viet set @content $viet ;
}
save :b ;
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try this too,

Comment: This command line reported errors, like "first line should be <open> eng.xml" etc... I dont know perl to understand and explain , maybe a screenshot, ill upload.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos: It worked for me, I just saved the code to `eng2viet.xsh` and ran `xsh eng2viet.xsh`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably tackle this in `perl`, using the rather excellent [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm) library. This comes bundled with [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)

I can't give a full example without some more XML example, but:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

my $source_eng = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'test_eng.xml');
my $source_viet = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'test_viet.xml'); 

foreach my $property ( $source_eng -> get_xpath('//Property') ) {
   my $name = $property -> att('name'); 
   my $first_match = $source_viet -> get_xpath("//Property[\@name=\'$name\']",0);

   if ( $first_match ) { 
       print "match found for $name\n";
       my $content = $first_match -> att('content'); 
       $property -> set_att('content', $content ); 
   }
}

$source_eng -> set_pretty_print('indented');
$source_eng -> print;
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try this option.

Comment: Sobrique, i made what you said, the script found matches and printed some data,  how can i output the right data from it?

Comment: The thing being modified is `$source_eng`, where it's updating the 'content' field on anything that matches from `$source_viet`. That `$source_eng -> print` prints to the screen the modified XML. You can write it to a file with: `open ( my $output, '>', 'results.xml') or warn $!; print {$output} $source_eng -> sprint;`

Comment: I can't give you anything better without sample XML and desired output.